# what is the running time for insertion of an element at some index of arrayList?

Tags: java, data-structures, arraylist, complexity-theory, big-o

I was wondering what is the running time for `add(index,E)` method of java `ArrayList`. According to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int) the running time for add operation is amortized `O(1)`. But in the description of [add(index,E)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29) it says that.

> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list.
>   Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any
>   subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).

So it looks like `O(N)`. I was wondering what do we have to trade for, if running time for this operation was to make `O(1)`. Is there any amortization work that can be done to make this operation `O(1)` and sacrifice running time for some other operation ?

I read that java `ArrayList` is backed by arrays, would changing the data structure help?

Comment: [regular add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)) is amortized O(1), [add at index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29) is amortized O(N)

Answer (score 3):

`ArrayList` has O(n)  time complexity for arbitrary indices of add/remove, but O(1) for the operation at the end of the list. **Closer** to O(1) lookup implies **may be something** like a [Hash Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) backed data structure with index as key and element as value. Insertion again will take O(n) time because it triggers a resize.

Comment: To which lookup operation that has `O(1)` time are you referring to?

Comment: do you mean add when you say lookup?

Answer (score 2):

A naive implementation of an array-backed list would copy each item to be moved on an insert as a separate operation. Fortunately, the bytes to be moved are all contiguous in memory and every operating system provides support for efficiently copying large chunks of memory in a single, fast operation.

So inserting into the middle of an array isn't as bad as you might think. Of course, changing the data structure to a linked list might prove to be faster if your application has the right kind of access pattern.

Comment: How would changing the data structure to linked list help? Insertion in linked list if O(1) agreed, but finding where to insert might take O(N) so doesn't that destroy our purpose?

Comment: Hence the caveat "if your application has the right kind of access pattern." For example, if you are walking down the list and based on what you find there you decide to insert items at or near your current location, then a linked list works great. If you need completely random access, then the linked list sucks.

Comment: well another aspect of linked list vs arrays is resizing. Java achieves amortized O(1) for add operation because of resizing.